# Building a (process) variable in Appian using the value of another one?

Tags: dynamic, backticks, appian

As far as I understand, it is not possible in Appian to dynamically construct (process) variable names, just like you would do e.g. with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) using backticks like `` MY_OBJECT=pv!MY_CONS_`extract(valueOfPulldown)` ``. Is that correct? Is there a workaround?

I have set of [Appian constants](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/19.4/Constants.html), let's call them `MY_CONS_FOO`, `MY_CONS_BAR`, `MY_CONS_LALA`, all of which are e.g. refering to an [Appian data store entity](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.1/Data_Stores.html). I would like to write an [Appian expression rule](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.1/Expression_Rules.html) which populates another variable `MY_OBJECT` of the same type (here: data store entity), depending e.g. of the options of a pull-down menu having the possible options stored in an array `MY_CONS_OPTIONS` looking as follows

```
FOO
BAR
LALA
```

I could of course build a lengthy case-structure which I have to maintain in addition to `MY_CONS_OPTIONS`, so I am searching for a more dynanmic approach using the [`extract()`](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/19.4/fnc_text_extract.html) function depending on `valueOfPulldown` as the chosen value of the pulldown-menu.

**Edit:** Here the expression-rule (in pseudo-code) I want to avoid:

```
if (valueOfPulldown = 'FOO') then MY_OBJECT=pv!MY_CONS_FOO
if (valueOfPulldown = 'BAR') then MY_OBJECT=pv!MY_CONS_BAR
if (valueOfPulldown = 'LALA') then MY_OBJECT=pv!MY_CONS_LALA
```

The goal is to be able to change the data store entity via pulldown-menu.

Comment: @Jakub asked: Can you provide more context around what you are trying to achieve? BTW this can help you find what is behind your constant: `fn!typeName(fn!typeOf(cons!YOUR_CONSTANT))`_

Comment: My answer: I would like to have some kind of _dynamic_ assignment of constants which (strictly speaking) would not be a constant any more, since hard-coding an expression rule requires me to change it every time a new option is added. I will try to edit-in a code snippet to clarify what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

This can help you find what is behind your constant.
`fn!typeName(fn!typeOf(cons!YOUR_CONSTANT))`.

Having in mind additional details I would do as follows:

1. Create separate expression that will combine details into list of Dictionary like below:

Expression results (er):

```
   {
      {dd_label: "label1", dd_value: 1, cons: "cons!YOUR_CONSTANT1" }
      ,{dd_label: "label2", dd_value: 2, cons: "cons!YOUR_CONSTANT2" }
    }
```

2. on UI for your dropdown control use er.dd_label as choiceLabels and er.dd_value as choiceValues
3. when user selects value on Dropdown save dropdown value to some local variable and then use it to find your const by doing:

`property( index(er, wherecontains(local!dropdownselectedvalue, tointeger(er.dd_value))), "cons")`

4. returned value of step 3 is your constant

This might not be perfect as you still have to maintain your dictionary but you can avoid long if...else statements.

As a alternative have a look on Decisions Tables in Appian https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.1/Appian_Decisions.html

Comment: Thanks for editing. Please use your commenting privilege to ask for more info beforehand if you need it for answering.